# SQL SELECT repeating rows from table for specific time interval

Tags: sql, select, db2, repeat

I have table and I want to find repeating rows for specific time interval (DATE is input parameter for SQL query) where it will list all rows with the same PERSON and TYPE value.

```
ID  DATE          PERSON   TYPE
1   01.01.2017    PERSON1  TYPE1
2   02.02.2017    PERSON1  TYPE1
3   03.03.2017    PERSON2  TYPE1
4   04.04.2017    PERSON2  TYPE2
5   05.05.2017    PERSON2  TYPE1
6   06.06.2017    PERSON1  TYPE2
```

So for example if DATE is between `01.01 and 04.04` it should list me rows with `ID 1 and 2.`

If DATE is between `01.01 and 06.06` it should list me rows with `ID 1, 2, 3` `and 5` because 1 and 2 have the same person and type in that interval and 3 and 5 have the same person and type in that interval.

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE>='01.01.2017' AND DATE<='06.06.2017'
```

but I am not sure even how to start to define this repeating clause based on PERSON and TYPE columns.
Maybe can INNER JOIN help with this if referencing the same table and matching those two columns and third column ID is different?: `TABLE.PERSON=TABLE.PERSON and TABLE.TYPE=TABLE.TYPE and TABLE.ID!=TABLE.ID` of course table is the same but different alias can be used for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try...

```
SELECT ID AS ID
FROM tableName
JOIN
(
    SELECT person AS person,
           type AS type,
           COUNT( person ) AS countOfPair
    FROM tableName
    WHERE date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
    GROUP BY person,
             type
) tempTable ON tableName.person = tempTable.person AND
               tableName.type = tempTable.type
WHERE countOfPair >= 2
```

The inner `SELECT` gathers each combination of `person` and `type` in between your start and end dates (please replace `startDate` and `endDate` with however you are referencing those) and performs a count of them.

The outer `SELECT` statement's `JOIN` then has the effect of appending the count of each combination to the end of each row containing that combination.  The outer `SELECT` then retrieves the `ID` from each row that has a repeated combination.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I don't know if your version has window analytic function):
(X is the name of your table)

```
SELECT Y.ID, Y.DATE, Y.PERSON, Y.TYPE
FROM (
   SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON, TYPE) AS RC
   FROM X 
   WHERE DATE >='01.01.2017' AND DATE <='04.04.2017'
    ) Y 
WHERE RC>1
```

Or this if it doesn't support them:

```
SELECT X.ID, X.DATE, X.PERSON, X.TYPE
FROM X
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT PERSON, TYPE, COUNT(*) AS RC
   FROM X 
   WHERE DATE >='01.01.2017' AND DATE <='04.04.2017'
    GROUP BY PERSON, TYPE
    ) Y ON X.PERSON = Y.PERSON AND X.TYPE = Y.TYPE
WHERE RC>1
```

I suggest to use always appropriate conversion for date datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tablename a NATURAL JOIN
  (SELECT person,type FROM tablename
   WHERE date>='01.01.2017' AND date<='06.06.2017'
   GROUP BY person, type HAVING COUNT(*)>1) b ;
```

The `NATURAL JOIN` would automatically use columns `person` and `type`.

Answer (score -2):

Add "DISTINCT" clause to avoid redundancy

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE>='01.01.2017' AND DATE<='06.06.2017'
```

Comment: This will return just one of each `ID` in that range.  It will not tell tehm which rows have repeating `Person` & `Type` combinations.